# What is different between using array and object as cache in memoizition?

Tags: javascript, memoization

The Fibonacci sequence is traditionally used to explain tree recursion.

```
function fibonacci(n) {
   if(n==0 || n == 1)
       return n;
   return fibonacci(n-1) + fibonacci(n-2);}
```

I want to implement the memoization solution. Here is my code:

```
  var fibonacci = (function(){
  var cache = [];
  return function(n){
    if(n==0 || n == 1){
      return n;
    }else{
      cache[n-1] = cache[n-1]||fibonacci(n-1);
      cache[n-2] = cache[n-2]||fibonacci(n-2);
      return cache[n-1]+cache[n-2];
    }
  }
})();
```

But here is another answer which is voted by many people as the best practice:

```
var fibonacci = (function () {
  var cache = {};

  return function(n) {

    // Base case
    if(n==0 || n == 1)
        return n;

    // Recurse only if necessary
    if(cache[n-2] === undefined)
      cache[n-2] = fibonacci(n-2);
    if(cache[n-1] === undefined)
      cache[n-1] = fibonacci(n-1);

    return cache[n-1] + cache[n-2];
  };
})();
```

I want to know what different is between using array and object as cache in memoizition?

Comment: I don't see a big difference. If anything, your solution with an array seems more straighforward (since you are only addressing things by positive integer index).

Comment: I think the real difference is that they call `n-2` before `n-1` (makes more sense) whereas you have that reversed.

Comment: Where did you find this answer?

Comment: It is on the [codewars](http://www.codewars.com/kata/memoized-fibonacci/solutions/javascript).

Comment: Why they call `n-2` before `n-1` makes more sense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The same difference that is always there between arrays and objects.

Arrays are supposedly optimised for integer properties, while objects do better on all kinds of property names, and especially sparse ones. For your application, the fibonacci sequence, arrays are suited better indeed.